# Issues with displaying comments under respective articles

Tags: php, mysql

Please I need your help with my script, I'm trying to pull all the comments of a particular article onto their respective pages.

The comments are displaying abnormally, in that it's displaying all the comments in the comment table to all the articles, even to articles that I've not made comments on.

**Homepage**

```
     $query = mysql_query(" SELECT
     c.username , c.comment_body,
     c.comment_date 
     FROM comment AS c  
     INNER JOIN home AS h ON
     c.article_id = h.home_id")
     or die (mysql_error());
```

**about page**

```
     $query6 = mysql_query(" SELECT
     c.username , c.comment_body,
     c.comment_date 
     FROM comment AS c  
    INNER JOIN about AS as ON
    c.article_id = as.about_id")
    or die (mysql_error());
```

**Comment Table**

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS`comment`(
     `comment_id` int(255),
     `article_id` int(255),
     `username` varchar(255) ,
     `comment_body` varchar(300),
     `comment_date` datetime,
     PRIMARY KEY (`comment_id`)
```

**About Table**

```
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `about` (
  `about_id` int(255),
  `about_head` varchar(255)
  `about_content` varchar(4000),
  `about_tags` varchar(255) ,
  `about_created` datetime,



     **Homepage Table**

  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `home` (
  `home_id` int(255),
  `home_head` varchar(255)
  `home_content` varchar(4000),
  `home_tags` varchar(255) ,
  `home_created` datetime,
```

Does anybody see where I'm going wrong?

Comment: I don't get your db structure. Where do you store "articles"? You seem to have a table for each page?

Comment: Each article are stored in their coresponding page tables. Like articles meant for the about page are stored inside the about table, and will appear on about.php.

Comment: Regarding the table structure, I'd have an extra column for the section, so you would have all articles in the same table.

Comment: If i do that do i still need to put a commentID in that articles table?

Comment: Do you mean an `article_id` in the comments table? That's what you have now, and that's correct. If you have a commentID in the articles table, each article can only have one single comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not telling SQL which article you are currently at, so it's fetching them all. You need a `WHERE` clause at the end of your queries, like this (example for "about"):

```
SELECT
    c.username, 
    c.comment_body,
    c.comment_date 
FROM comment AS c  
    INNER JOIN about AS a ON
    c.article_id = a.about_id
WHERE a.about_id = ?
```

Replace the question mark with the actual ID of the current page. If you're using [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php), let it do the replacement for you when you call [`execute`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) on the statement.

Answer (score 0):

Your "about page" doesn't specify a `WHERE` clause to filter the results for only the results you want.  Change it to something like:

```
SELECT
c.username , c.comment_body,
c.comment_date 
FROM comment AS c  
INNER JOIN about AS as ON
c.article_id = as.about_id
WHERE c.article_id = 123;
```